# is it possible to put EditText in LiveWallPaper?

Tags: android, android-edittext, live-wallpaper

is it possible to add edittext box in setting of android live wall paper ? and if yes then how to set it in the setting and retrieve it's value ?

Comment: it's not possible put `EditText` in `WallpaperService `

Comment: Why you want to put EditText in there? If you need some input field, you must create a widget.

Comment: actually i am creating a lwp in which user can enter his/her name, for which i wanted to put edittext

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally i got the ans. it simple

```
<EditTextPreference
        android:title="@string/settings_name"
        android:summary="@string/settings_name_summary"
        android:key="fn_name">
</EditTextPreference>
```

This will give edit text box in setting of lwp :)